# Move existing text PDF using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am new in PDFBOX, and I am trying to move text from a coordinate into another coordinate. is it possible to move an existing text?

here is my pdf screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQJsJ.jpg)

I want to move B.

Comment: There is no general solution, PDF isn't made for editing existing PDFs, and there are many ways to position text, so there would be many ways to change their position. Please share your PDF.

Comment: okay. thanks @TilmanHausherr. I just thinking to replace existing text to "" then I create new text using PDPageContentStream.showText then I newLineAtOffset the new coordinates. But first I need to know the coordinates before. How about that?

Comment: How can the text you want to move be identified? If there are easy-to-implement criteria for that, both moving and removing are possible.

Comment: Try the `PrintTextLocations.java` and the `RemoveAllText.java` examples in the source code download. Also try PDFDebugger so that you see how a content stream looks.